# Linear transformations on vector spaces

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I'm currently reading up on linear transformations of vector spaces which has gotten me somewhat confused. For instance, there are dilation and contraction operators which can operate on vector spaces in such a way that $T(c\vec{u}) = cT(\vec{u})$.

What bothers me is the fact that a vector space per definition already contains all scalars of $\vec{u}$, and thus I'm not actually sure what the transformation does on the vector space. It doesn't seem to change the actual set of vectors which make up the space. How does a linear transformation on a vector space differ from a linear transformation on a vector?

What am I missing?

Comment: Quite complex, and probably not what you want: A linear map preserves the vector space structure; hence it's a $1$-morphism in $\mathrm{Vect}_{\mathbf{K}}$, where $\mathbf{K}$ is a field. In such situations, category theory comes in use - you learn to view mappings that preserve some structure in a very nice and comforting way. However, I don't think you should be worrying about that now; this is just a (possibly helpful) comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your last sentence I believe that you are just confused by the terminology of having a function/operator/map/transformation (all different words for the same thing) on a vector space.

What you have written, $T(c\vec{u}) = cT(\vec{u})$, is true by definition for any **linear** transformation and is not a particular property of dilation and contraction transformations. If you instead write $T(c\vec{u}) = c\vec{u}$ you have defined a contraction or dilation transformation (depending on the value of $c$).

The last thing that I believe may confuse you is when you write "I'm not actually sure what the transformation does on the vector space". Consider the vector space $\mathbb{R}$ and the linear transformation $f$ defined by

$$f:\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} \\ f(x)=2x$$

It is a linear transformation of $\mathbb{R}$ that maps the element $\omega$ to $2\omega$. But the range of the function is still the same space as the domain.